# How to call scene method before application goes to background?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I need to pause the game before my game goes to background, so when it comes to foreground again I see the pause dialog in my game. To show pause dialog I have a scene method. How to call scene method right before application goes to background? I see that the following method is the right place:

```
-(void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application
{
    if( [navController_ visibleViewController] == director_ )
        [director_ stopAnimation];
}
```

Should I just get the scene from director `runningScene`, cast it to my scene class and then send pause message to it or that way is ugly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this scenario, I think Notifications are the cleanest and safest option. You can just post a notification from applicationDidEnterBackground and receive wherever you want to perform certain actions like:

In App Delegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application {
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"EnteringBackground" object:nil];
}
```

In GameScene:

```
- (void)onEnter {
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(showPausePopup) name:@"EnteringBackground" object:nil];
}

- (void)onExit {
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)showPausePopup:(NSNotification*)notification {
   // Code to show popup
}
```